# html-webpack-plugin doesn't inject css and meta tag into the generate file

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I run my vue app with webpack, which use webpack-simple template. My webpack setting is:

```
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',  // 由于将index.html打包至dist下，生产环境设为'/'
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
```

originHtml:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://at.alicdn.com/t/font_9remcre60b3dte29.css">
    <title>earease</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

generateHtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>earEase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/build.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Why the css and meta tag doesn't inject into the generated html file?

Answer (score 0):

Your webpack is not grabbing the original html template. It is just generating a new one as you can see by the `<title>` tag on your output html.

Change your config so that HTMLWebpackPlugin can read the template file:

```
{
  ...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'My App',
      filename: 'assets/admin.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've set like this:plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'dist/index.html',
            template: 'index.html'
        })
    ],              but it still can't work

Comment: @user6542007 Is the index.html file in the same directory as the webpack config and is the html file going to the dist/ folder? Can you show me the contents of it?

Comment: @user6542007 Did you specify the html loader properly? https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md

Comment: May be all you said I've set properly. You can see this capture.![capture](http://i1.piimg.com/567571/d6aad5e608eb19c9.jpg)